# api fetch right after useState doesn't retrieve the updated data because state is not updated before api fetch

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to implement a filter form. I have all the filters in a useState hook.

```
const [filters, setFilters] = useState({});
```

And then I have a fetch function that calls the api with the filters. Filtering works as expected; clicking on Apply button after all filters are set retrieves the proper records as expected.

Then there's the remove filter function. To do that I do this:

```
const clearFilters = () => {
 setFilters({}) //tried with setFilters( () => {} ) as well
 fetch();
}
```

The problem is filters doesn't get removed the first time, but on second click it works.

I am aware that the suggested approach is using `useEffect` but the problem with this approach is that I do not want to call the fetch function every time `filters` changes. I want to be able to update the view only when the `Apply Filters` or 'Remove Filters` is clicked.

I tried this approach from another SO answer as well, but the behaviour is the same.

```
Promise.resolve()
 .then(() => {
   setFilterState({});
 })
 .then(() => {
   fetch();
 });
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I'm conscious why you are not using two separate function to do this like `async function setFilter` and `async function removeFilter`

Answer (score 1):

You may use the react-dom `flushSync`. This function takes a callback in which you can update state synchronously. Everything executed after `flushSync` will have access to the updated value of the state.

Be careful anyway not to use this function too much as it may result to poor performances.

You could write your function this way:

```js
import { flushSync } from 'react-dom';

const clearFilters = () => {
 flushSync(() => {
   setFilters({})
 })
 fetch();
}
```

Comment: this was the only thing I did not try; I did not know about flushSync and this looked so promising but did not work. That convinced me that there was another issue with my implementation. I ended up changing the entire logic to get my filters to work. But flushSync looks like a very useful function so thanks for this and I am upvoting this answer for that!

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a state for the clearFilter and add a useEffect for that.

```
const App = () => {
    const [clearFilterState, setClearFilterState] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
       if(clearFilterState) {
           // call your API here
           setClearFilterState(false);
        }
    },[clearFilterState])   


    const clearFilter =() => {
        setFilter({});
        setClearFilterState(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be more helpful if you had a basic implementation

Answer (score 0):

Could you have a state that handles true/false and renders the filters from the fetch-call if the state is true, and returns an initialState if the state is false?

I.e when the `apply filters` is clicked, the boolean state is true and renders the filters, and when the `remove filters` is clicked, the boolean state changes and the filters gets set to an initialState as {}

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the filter object in the fetch function.  So, the clear filter function will be as follows:

```
const clearFilters = () => {
 setFilters({})
 fetchFilter({});
}
```

The fetch function will be

```
cont fetchFilter = (filter)=> {
     fetch('url', filter)
     ...other function's side effects
}
```